# How to model several "pauses" in a time registration application

Tags: database, database-design

I am trying to create a website, where i can create assignments and record the amout of time each assignment takes. There should be a start, stop, pause and continue button.

I figured having a start and stop date for each assignment in the database. This way when pushing the start button, the current datetime would be saved, and when pushing the stop button, the current datetime would be recorded aswell. Then i could subtract the two dates and get the amount of time it took to complete the assignment.

But what if want to pause an assignment, and continue it on a later date? Substracting the start and stop date would not return the actual amount of time spent on the assignment this way.

How do i go about this?

Thanks

On the basis of @Gilbert Le Blanc's answer, i have created a small C# application to demonstrate the solution, if anyone should need this:

```
class Program
    {
        static List<DateTime> datetimes;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // DateTime(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32) 
            // Initializes a new instance of the DateTime structure to the specified year, month, day, hour, minute, and second.

            datetimes = new List<DateTime>();

            datetimes.Add(new DateTime(2013, 08, 18, 15, 15, 51));
            datetimes.Add(new DateTime(2013, 08, 19, 15, 15, 51));
            datetimes.Add(new DateTime(2013, 08, 20, 15, 15, 51));
            //datetimes.Add(new DateTime(2013, 08, 21, 15, 15, 51));

            double numberOfMinutes = CalculateTimeInMinutes(datetimes.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ToList());
            bool isRunning = IsOdd(datetimes.Count);

        }


        // Hvis der er et ulige antal rækker, kører opgaven stadig
        // Hvis der er et lige antal rækker, er opgaven pauset
        private static bool IsOdd(int value)
        {
            return value % 2 != 0;
        }

        private static double CalculateTimeInMinutes(List<DateTime> timelist) 
        {

            double numberOfMinutes = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < timelist.Count; i++)
            {
                int nextDate = i + 1;

                if (nextDate <= timelist.Count - 1)
                {
                    TimeSpan ts = timelist[i] - timelist[nextDate];
                    Console.WriteLine(ts.TotalMinutes);
                    numberOfMinutes = numberOfMinutes + ts.TotalMinutes;
                }
            }

            return numberOfMinutes;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would create a separate time segment table.

There would be one row for each start / stop time stamp.

Your web site would only need start and stop buttons.  I'm assuming that there's a way for the user of the web site to indicate which assignment she or he is currently working on.

You would sum up the time segment rows over a week, two weeks, or a month, depending on your reporting needs.

Comment: I see. I would like to sum up the rows in minutes. I know how to calculate the minutes between two datetimes, but what would be a good approach/algorithm to use when there are multiple rows?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  duration = stop time - start time.  duration + duration + etc. for as many rows as written for an assignment.